# Failed to connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import -connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test -username root -P -table transactions -m 1
```

When executing the above command, I get thefollowing exception.

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
18/02/10 02:06:16 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.12.0
Enter password: 
18/02/10 02:06:22 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
18/02/10 02:06:22 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
18/02/10 02:06:23 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `transactions` AS t LIMIT 1
18/02/10 02:06:23 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `transactions` AS t LIMIT 1
18/02/10 02:06:23 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/6c95208490848382aa6375de4e4f81bf/transactions.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
18/02/10 02:06:27 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/6c95208490848382aa6375de4e4f81bf/transactions.jar
18/02/10 02:06:27 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
18/02/10 02:06:27 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
18/02/10 02:06:27 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
18/02/10 02:06:27 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
18/02/10 02:06:27 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of transactions
18/02/10 02:06:27 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
18/02/10 02:06:31 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
18/02/10 02:06:31 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032
18/02/10 02:06:33 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:34 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:35 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:36 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:37 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:38 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:39 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:40 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:41 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:42 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
18/02/10 02:06:42 WARN ipc.Client: Failed to connect to server: quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15:8032: retries get failed due to exceeded maximum allowed retries number: 10
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:648)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:744)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3000(Client.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1555)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy20.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.getNewApplication(ApplicationClientProtocolPBClientImpl.java:217)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.getNewApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.getNewApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate.getNewJobID(ResourceMgrDelegate.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getNewJobID(YARNRunner.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1304)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1325)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:203)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:176)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:273)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:513)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:621)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Sqoop. Your resource manager is not started. Please verify services are running in Cloudera Manager

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, I got it solved when i start my Resource Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Port 8032 is the resource manager for YARN.

Sqoop is trying to execute a MapReduce job, but cannot without it running.

You'll need to start it from Cloudera Manager, or from the terminal, if you are comfortable with it